# Including covariates in simultaneous vs. hierarchical regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, covariance

If you are computing a regression, want to know if specific IVs predict the DV when controlling for covariates (one included because age was different between IV groups, another because it is significantly correlated with DV), do I do a simultaneous regression or a hierarchical regression with covariates in step one and IVs in step 2? Please provide an academic source, if possible.

Thank you!